# Can I undelete my question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Earlier today, I posted a question and self-answer that proved unpopular (-3 to both). I deleted the answer so I could rethink it, but I also deleted the question, thinking it worked the same way. I see, however, that's not the case.

It was not my intention to permanently delete the question. Is there a way I, or someone else, can undelete it?

(The question was related to identifying a scale based on a set of notes or chords.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can undelete it yourself; go to the 'questions' tab on your profile (or visit [this link](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions)) and click the 'recently deleted questions' link at the bottom. There you'll find your question and you'll be able to undelete it.

Comment: Got it. I see the list shows questions "deleted in the last 60 days". Does that mean that after 60 days the deletion does in fact become permanent?

Comment: No, if you have a link to the question you can always visit and undelete it. If you have 10k reputation, you can even [search for deleted content you own](/help/privileges/moderator-tools).